# where to put helper methods for controllers only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am looking to write certain methods for processing strings, and other tasks that take place in numerous of my controllers. I know its bad practice to include helpers in your controller, so I was just wondering, where is the best place to put application wide methods used in controllers?

I realize some of you will say to put them in models, but you have to realize that not all my controllers have an associated model. Any and all input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need to use a method in the application scope then I would suggest that you keep those methods inside the application controller and in order to use them inside views.. declare those as helper methods.

For example,

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 helper_method :current_user, :some_method

 def current_user
   @user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
 end

 def some_method
 end
end
```

Comment: The problem is that if there are many helper methods, `ApplicationController` can become unwieldy. I prefer breaking the methods out into helper files by category, and including the files in `ApplicationController`, as suggested in Semyon Perepelitsa's answer.

Answer (score 13):

I tend to put them into helpers. The fact that they are included in views
automatically haven't been a problem for me. You can also place them into
something like app/concerns/ or lib/

I don't like cluttering ApplicationController with private methods
because this often becomes a mess.

Example:

```
module AuthenticationHelper
  def current_user
    @current_user # ||= ...
  end

  def authenticate!
    redirect_to new_session_url unless current_user.signed_in?
  end
end

module MobileSubdomain
  def self.included(controller)
    controller.before_filter :set_mobile_format
  end

  def set_mobile_format
    request.format = :mobile if request.subdomain == "m"
  end
end

class ApplicationController
  include AuthenticationHelper
  include MobileSubdomain
end
```

Comment: That's what I do, too.

Comment: This makes more sense to me than stuffing every helper method into the Application Controller.

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest to put them in `lib` folder. So for example I have:

```
lib/utils/string_utils

module StringUtils

  def foo
     ...
  end
end

class BarController < ActionController::Base
  include StringUtils
end
```

This demonstrates good methodology called **Fat model, Thin controller**, in this case we are using Mixins instead of Models to separate logic but idea is same. You want your controllers as simple as possible.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on your needs. I will provide here 2 examples. Both of them are just a custom libraries, located under `lib` directory.

**First example - "custom string processing"**

```
# lib/filters.rb
module Filters

  # Converts value to canonical view
  def self.phone(value)
    # remove all non-digits
    clean_value = value.gsub(/\D/, '')

    country_codes = configus.phone.country_codes
    area_code = configus.phone.defaults.area_code

    case clean_value.length
      when 7
        "#{area_code}#{clean_value}"
      when 11
        # remove country code only if phone starts with the allowed country code
        if country_codes.include?(clean_value[0].to_i)
          clean_value[1..-1]
        else
          clean_value
        end
      else clean_value
    end
  end

# usage
# app/api/phones_controller.rb
class Api::PhonesController < Api::ApplicationController

  def exists
    if params[:q]
      clean_value = Filters.phone(params[:q])
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

**Second example - helper for flash messages**

```
# lib/flash_helper.rb
module FlashHelper
  def flash_translate(key, options = {})
    scope = [:flash, :controllers]
    scope += params[:controller].split('/')
    scope << params[:action]

    t(key, {:scope => scope}.merge(options))
  end
end

# app/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include FlashHelper
end

# usage
# app/your_controller.rb
class YourController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @object = Object.new(params[:object])

    if @object.save
      flash[:success] = flash_translate(:success)
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Note: do not forget to add `lib` dir to the autoload paths. In `config/application.rb` add/modify this line `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)`.
So for me the answer is `lib` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Rails 4 there is a dedicated folder for it `app/controllers/concerns`. So you can create a module there and then include it in a specific controller(s) or in ApplicationController if you need it available throughout all your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

In case those methods are used in numerous controllers, I would define them in `application_controller.rb`. Every controller will inherits from it and will be capable to use any method defined there